# Cat 6 life expectancy

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling

how long will cat 6 cable survive outside if it is not an external grade cable.

No sunlight touches the cable but only cold temperatures of around -10c, everyday every year.

the cable has no holes, and it is above ground level flat on a wall.

Comment: The bigger factor is moisture.

Comment: how would moisture effect it, if it has no  holes?

Comment: The plastic insulation isn't completely waterproof.  And there can be microscopic holes.  Even without direct sunlight, I'd expect some UV-caused deterioration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indoor UTP cabling cannot withstand moisture. It may seem like the sheath is waterproof, but it is not. Water changes the dielectric properties of the cable. If your business depends on the network, then it really needs to spend some money to do it correctly.

---

Outside cabling is also subject to stricter regulation, e.g. it cannot extend more than 50 feet into a building, and it must have proper grounding, bonding, and lightning protection, etc. Doing something like you describe can get the building red-tagged for occupation until the situation is corrected, and it can lead to fines for every day it is out of compliance. There can also be stiff civil and criminal liabilities in the event of a disaster, like a fire.

Comment: How would you make the ethernet cable lightning resistant?

Comment: There are different things you can do, such as enclosing inside metal conduit that is properly grounded and bonded and connected to lightning protectors. This is a huge subject that is too large to discuss here. Outside Plant cable installation is a specialty, and many installers will not touch it. This is where you hire an expert.

Comment: What you’re really asking is “How can I get away with not doing the right thing?”  There’s no answer for that.

Comment: ron maupin, i can't put it in a conduit as it is flat against the wall with round cable plugs,. would lightning still be an issue for me? The cable doesn't touch the ground, it's only on the wall outside my house.

Comment: Questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].